# My passwordless authentication approach

Tags: authentication

I implemented a passwordless authentication with a good UX in mind. But I am not a security expert so I am asking for your advice.

This is the authentication flow:

1. User types in email address
2. client send email to API
3. API creates User if not exists
4. API generates a short living jwt with a UUID and saves the user id and session id as claims
5. token id and session id get saved to db with a confirmed flag
6. API sends this token to the email address
7. User clicks the link on any device of choice
8. if token is valid and the claims match the data in the db the confirmed flag is set to true and a last_login field is set to the token's iat (not really sure know if I need that ^^)
9. Meanwhile the client where the user logged in polls for confirmation and updates session if login was confirmed

Comment: You have not described authentication. You're just linking the email to the session.

Comment: OAUTH is getting close to passwordless. I'd link your service to an OAUTH provider

Comment: But isn't that equivalent? The authentication happens where the token is validated and the claims match the data in the db.

Comment: I have considered using Auth0 passwordless but I don't like that the session is sent to the client where the link gets opened. E.g. the user logs on desktop and opens the link on mobile.

Comment: You are not describing authentication, as I said. At best, you are authenticating the email account, not the user. This is 0.5-factor-authentication. I cannot change a password. And you are relying on the security of email transmissions and storage, which can be very exposed.

Comment: Also I tried magic.link but I wanna stay independent from third party services.

Comment: Of course you rely on email security with passwordless/magic link authentication but thats the same for the 'forgot password' link on password based systems. I have also in mind to offer some kind of a second factor.

Comment: Somehow I need the proof (the jwt) and how if not from the users email account? Also it's bound to the client where the login originated.

Comment: Take a look at magic.link again. It delegates auth to the email client. They are very clear about that. This is not authentication. This is "logging in". This is "gaining access". You push actual authentication and account security to the email client. You need to be very clear about that yourself. Is your service at a low level of sensitivity to have that make sense?

Comment: Ok yes I am clear that this approach delegates it to the email account then I mean logging in instead but the email account is I think the most vulnerable part anyway if the user does not secure it properly. I think security will be a concern in my service as it will be an e-commerce service.

Comment: Ok, then I'm glad we got clear on that. PCI-DSS might have some things to say about a passwordless approach. I know we aren't talking about your login process, but I fear for your design not being fit-for-purpose even if it was secure.

Comment: Oh ok thats definitely a thing that I was not aware of, thanks. I will do my research on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you rely only on the hability to access to the declared email address, I think you should have eavesdropping detection methods.

For example, in your current flow, if an evil E accesses to the mailbox after the owner, E can still click the link and be authenticated.
Also, every NSA router (so every router ^^) between your API and the user's mail server can read the token if the email is not encrypted (which is not only under your control).

So a "burn after using" should be implemented for the token.
So if the token is automatically eavesdropped and used before the legitimate user, he will see that someone took the access (because the token will be burned and his access will be refused). And if the token is acceded after the legitimate user, it has no value anymore.

So the authentication token, after been used, must be different from the session token used to maintain access for the user.

Comment: Most people these days are accessing email either through a web interface (which will be HTTPS), or preconfigured apps that will only dial to authenticated servers over some form of TLS.  Specifically to prevent snooping, and because it's easier..

Answer (score 0):

### **The process itself**

What you described is more like a user creation process, I can't see where you are confirming the identity of the user.

If someone has the user's email password, it is game over, so, this may no be as passwordless as desired.

### **email security**

Another point is that email protocols are not always secure, on the contrary, the default is to transmit emails in clear text from a server to another. The exception may be the user interfaces, which is preferred to use TLS (secure internet browsing), but all the rest is likely to go unencrypted. So, relying in email to replace passwords may not the best idea.